# Unable to hit the servlet using chrome web driver

Tags: java, selenium, servlets, gwt, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to hit my own servlet using selenium chrome web driver within the same web application, but the code doesn't hit the break-point I set in my servlet.

Following is the code I used to call the servlet,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);

String PROXY = <proxy ip> + ":" + <proxy port>;     
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
options.merge(capabilities);

ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

webdriver.get("http://<some ip>:<some port>/myApp/myServlet")
```

When I call the servlet simply from browser using url

`http://<some ip>:<some port>/myApp/myServlet`

it reaches to break-point. But when I tries to do the same from webdriver, it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me with this?

**UPDATE** - Below is the servlet which handles request.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In MyServlet -> doPost()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In MyServlet -> doGet()");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the servlet code that handles the request.

Comment: @aframestor updated the question with servlet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue, the proxy address I was using was causing the problem, when I changed the proxy, I was able to hit the servlet successfully.

To manage it better, I have maintained a pool of proxies and added code to remove proxy from pool if proxy is invalid, also added code to provide next valid proxy from pool.